# custom post type don’t appear in the home page

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, hierarchical

I would like to have different types of posts on my blog, e.g.: articles, film descriptions, book descriptions, links with short descriptions, quotations, historical events, characters, artwork, musical works, terms, etc. They should be grouped in hierarchical catalogues and hierarchical tags. Theoretically, this plug-in provides me with the possibility to do it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/. There is only a problem with it – custom post types don’t appear on the home page: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-dont-appear-in-the-main-colllection/. I’m learning php, but it will take a lot of time before I get the right knowledge. I could hire a programmer, but first I would like to do a good research. I believe that there is another simpler way. Does anyone know it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find `functions.php` in your theme and add this code:

```
function add_custom_pt( $query ) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'cptslug1', 'cptslug2' ) );
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_custom_pt' );
```

Change array values to match your post type slugs (add as many as you need), but keep 'post'.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `pre_get_posts` hook to modify the `$query` and include your custom post types in the search.

Add the following to your theme's `functions.php` file.

```
function modify_query( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'articles', 'film_descriptions', 'book_descriptions', 'characters' );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_query', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: My bad, I'm in the habit of seperating actions and filters into their own files on a custom theme I've been working on. I've updated my answer, thanks for your comment!

Comment: Since $query is defined globally and this is an action hook, nothing needs to be returned. I've incorporated your other suggestions into the answer. Thanks again!